# Get keys under specific datatype in Redis

Tags: redis

I am new to Redis. Can I get somehow (or using a command)the keys under each data structure?
For example:

> KEYS TYPE STRING

- keystr1
- keystr2

> KEYS TYPE SET

- keySet1
- keySet2

Comment: Have a look at the [`SCAN` command](https://redis.io/commands/scan)?

Comment: Yeah, that works for me,Thanks a lot !

Comment: ```SCAN 0 TYPE set```